# Why stand during Psalm 29 during Kabbalat Shabbat?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, minhag

In the shuls I've davened in (American, Ashkenazi), we always stand during [Psalm 29](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.29?lang=bi) during Kabbalat Shabbat. Why do we do this? What makes it different from the other psalms?

Comment: Psalm 29 is recited immediately after 99 within the Ashkenazic community. 99 has the theme of us standing before the King - [This theme then continues throughout the other Psalms, in which man is portrayed standing before the greatness of the Creator, His majesty and splendor.](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/halakha/orach-chaim/prayer-and-blessings/kabbalat-shabbat). Maybe that is why?

Answer (score 1):

The beginning of an answer...I will try and locate some sources.

It says on the OU site [here](https://www.ou.org/community/tefilllah/mizmor-ledovid-anah-bakoach/):

> After we recite the five consecutive psalms that correspond to the first five days of the week, **we rise from our seats and recite Psalm 29 which corresponds to the sixth day, Erev Shabbat. We stand up in honor and in awe of the presence of G-d that we experience in recognition that Shabbat the Messianic Day of Eternity has arrived.** We sing joyously Havu Lashem Bnei Eilim…. – You the children of our Patriarchs, Give unto G-d, Give unto Him your honor and strength, and bow down in this holy space.

I saw similarly that Mizmor LeDovid corresponds to erev shabbos [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/the-order-of-prayer-and-kiddush-when-yom-tov-coincides-with-shabbos/#_ftn5) which attributes the idea to Sichas Kodesh 2 p. 121

Comment: Standing to accept shabbat then probably made sense before lecha dodi became popular. Now that we don't accept shabbat till later this may not apply. (This is the danger of moving a carefully choreographed kabbalistic outdoor ritual into a shul: things get messed up and no one notices)